# peverify: Method is not visible?

Tags: c#, il, peverify

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm generating a dll that uses code in my current assembly. Here's a simplified version containing only the code that that's causing the issue.

```
static void Main()
{
    Swift.Init();
}

public static class Swift
{
    public static int GetTypeId(object obj)
    {
            return 0;
    }

    public static void Init()
    {
            var getTypeIdMethod = typeof(Swift).GetMethod("GetTypeId",
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

            var asmBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Asm"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
            var modBuilder = asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("Mod", "SerTest.dll");
            var typeBuilder = modBuilder.DefineType("TEST", TypeAttributes.Public);
            var methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("SWITCH",
                MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static,
                CallingConventions.Standard,
                typeof(void), new Type[] { typeof(Stream), typeof(object) });

            // arg0: Stream, arg1: object
            var il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
            il.DeclareLocal(typeof(int));

            // load and store id
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);                   // push object
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, getTypeIdMethod);     // pop object, pass to GetTypeId, push id
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);                   // pop, store in local
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            typeBuilder.CreateType();
            asmBuilder.Save("SerTest.dll");
    }
}
```

peverify gives:

```
[IL]: Error: [C:\Users\vexe\Desktop\MyExtensionsAndHelpers\Solution\CustomSerializer\bin\Release\SerTest.dll : TEST::SWITCH][offset 0x00000001] Method is not visible.
1 Error(s) Verifying SerTest.dll
```

What does this error mean? and what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here's what the generated method looks like in ildasm:

```
.method public static void  SWITCH(class [mscorlib]System.IO.Stream A_0,
                                   object A_1) cil managed
{
  // Code size       8 (0x8)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init (int32 V_0)
  IL_0000:  ldarg.1
  IL_0001:  call       int32 [CustomSerializer]Serializer.Swift::GetTypeId(object)
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ret
} // end of method TEST::SWITCH
```

Comment: Is the assembly you're generating this code from accessible to PEVerify when you're running it? That is, is "CustomSerializer.dll/exe" in the same directory or the GAC?

Comment: @JeroenMostert CustomSerializer.exe and SerTest.dll are in the same directory yes.

Comment: Also, just checked the C# code in ILSpy, it didn't throw any errors when viewing the class (sometimes it does if the code was invalid) and displayed the correct code: "int typeId = Swift.GetTypeId(obj);"

Comment: The only way I can reproduce this error is if the method `Swift.GetTypeId` is indeed not public (because `Swift` is nested in a non-public type, for example). But this doesn't appear to be the case in the IL you posted.

Comment: Silly me! Could have sworn I checked it to make sure the method was public. Convert to answer if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Method is not visible" means the method referenced is not visible to the assembly calling it. If you're not using [`InternalsVisibleTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute) (which PEVerify doesn't appear to understand, by the way) or [`protected internal`](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/10/29/what-does-protected-internal-mean.aspx), that means: the method must be a public method of a visible class, and a visible class is a public class optionally nested in a visible class. If you don't like that recursive definition: it's `public` all the way <s>down</s> up.

The code as posted should work (`Swift` is a non-nested public class and `GetTypeId` a public method), so the problem is in the code as not posted.